# Sharing services between two Angular apps

Tags: angular, git, ionic-framework, version-control

I am currently developing a marketplace in Ionic/Angular, which is splited into two different apps, one for sellers and another for clients. Due to there are some common features for both roles I've decided to create common services. The problem I want to solve is that when I modify this type of services in one project, currently I must copy the new changes manually to the other app's same service. This when you have to modify frequently these services is a tedious task so I want to automatise this process. Every approach is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Separate the services as an angular library project? So both applications can reference it.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks